# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, error-handling

**full error:** Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Source Code\displaysalesdetailed.php on line 48

Here is what I have there:

```
    $msgtocustomer = "You have sent purchase request for - $rsproduct[title]. To check the quality of the produce,
     you can contact $rsseller[
    seller_name] at $rsseller[mobile_no]. Farmer's Address: $rsseller[seller_address], $rs13city[city], 
$rs12state[state], $rs1country['country'].  ";
```

Comment: Which one is line 48 ?

Comment: You could try surrounding each of your array variables with `{` and `}`, this can remove confusion for the parser. Is there really a line break part-way through a variable name, or only when you post the code here? Why do you sometimes put single-quotes around the index name, and sometimes not?

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
$msgtocustomer = "You have sent purchase request for - {$rsproduct['title']}. To check the quality of the produce,
     you can contact {$rsseller['
    seller_name']} at {$rsseller['mobile_no']}. Farmer's Address: {$rsseller['seller_address']}, {$rs13city['city']}, 
{$rs12state['state']}, {$rs1country['country']}.  ";
```